# Проблема с переименованием файлов

Tags: c, массивы, windows, функции

Есть кусок кода, он должен переименовывать заданные файлы: 1.exe и 1.txt 
    меняя их на: test.test, но проблема в том, что при запуске всё работает, но 
    срабатывает только это: rename(fname, new); и переименовывается только файл 
    1.exe , а второй 1.txt не переименовывается, мне кажется , что программа 
    останавливается на первой функции rename(fname, new);
    Что необходимо сделать, дабы срабатывала вторая функция тоже.
    Надеюсь на вашу помощь)

```
    char new[20] = "test.test";

    char fname[30] = "1.exe";

    char name[40] = "1.txt";

    rename(fname, new);
    rename(name, new);
```

Comment: Как вы себе представляете два файла с одинаковым именем в одной директории?

Comment: Это тестовые 2 файла, созданные мною

Comment: Еще раз. Вы двум разным файлам даете *одинаковое* новое имя.

Comment: И будет ли это работать , если указать только расширение ".exe"

Comment: Да, одинаковое новое имя

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что у двух файлов не может быть одинаковое имя?

Comment: [Why you can't have two Files with the same name in the same directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722114/why-you-cant-have-two-files-with-the-same-name-in-the-same-directory).

Comment: Чтобы сработала вторая функция нужно переименовывать второй файл в другое имя, отличающееся от первого.

Comment: Да, точно, запуталась просто, спасибо за помощь)